# import gensim vs import gensim.test.utils

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding

The following line works fine:

```
import gensim
```

while the following line generates error:

```
import gensim.test.utils
```

Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-49e2788ad1a0> in <module>()
----> 1 import gensim.test.utils

ImportError: No module named 'gensim.test.utils'
```

I was working on converting GloVe to word2vec format:
[glove2word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/glove2word2vec.html)

Comment: Try `from gensim.test import utils`.

Comment: @erip. I tried it and got back: 'ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'`

Comment: Found solution: update to gensim 3.4 from gensim 3.1